# Is it possible to move variable's values from one class to another class without inheritance in java?

Tags: java, class, class-design, static-members, argument-passing

I have learnt how to call methods and even variables between two classes. I wanted to know if you can move values from one class to another without using inheritance. Here is an example:

1. I create two classes: class1 and class2.
2. I enter a variable with a value in class1.
3. Move a variable's value to class2.
4. Let the value to be tested by if statements in class2.
5. The output in class 2 can be moved to class1 or method with the output in class2 can be called within class1.

This is not a real program architecture though, it's just for my learning purposes. Thank you.
Update:
I was asked to post some code of what I have done to show the idea above.
Here is one class:

```
class MainClass
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("You have entered: " + args[0]);
    static int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    SubClass.calc(); //I believe I override it by passing value to a method within SubClass
}

}
```

Here is the second class:

```
class SubClass
{
    public static void calc()
{
    System.out.println("This is the output" + MainClass.num);
}
}
```

I tried to move my value in args[0] from MainClass to SubClass, but I get an error when I try to cast it from string to int data type:

```
pavel@pavel-OptiPlex-GX270:~/myjava$ javac MainClass.java
MainClass.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
static int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                                  ^
symbol:   variable args
location: class MainClass
1 error
```

Is there anything I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: Pavel, you need to post some code to show us what you have tried.  And you need to post it to stackoverflow, not here.

Comment: Hi @pavelexpertov , I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but this path don't looks like a good one. Try to refactor your code in a way it can comunicate passing parameters.

Comment: I have some answers below. If you can't see, I think my post got moved to stackoverflow. And for some weird reason I see my post on programmer's site as well stackoverflow's one.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delcare a static variable inside a method:

Try editing your main class like this:

```
public class MainClass {

    private static int num;

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println("You have entered: " + args[0]);
        num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        SubClass.calc();

        //even better, pass in the argument
        SubClass.calc2(num);
    }

    public static int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

}
```

And your `SubClass` like this:

```
public class SubClass {
    public static void calc() {
        System.out.println("This is the output" + MainClass.getNum()); //invoke the public getter method. We hid the original num variable with private keyword
    }

    public static void calc2(int number) { 
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you have to put getNum() method in the MainClass? I thought you can call method in another class to output the number.

Comment: I didn't. But it's common to hide the variables from the "outside" world, and expose *accessors* (i.e. get and set methods; in this case, the get method)

Comment: Ok thank you. What are accessors though, I am just in a learning process so I am trying to learn everything I can.

Comment: Accessors is just the name for methods that follow certain coding standard and access the class fields (variables). Read more here: http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/accessormutator.htm

Answer (score 1):

```java
SubClass.calc(); //I believe I override it by passing value to a method within SubClass
```

**No**, you are not overriding it. Only when you `extends` another class then overriding comes into the picture. Also remember that you can't override `static` members because they belongs to Class. You don't have to make instance of Class to invoke them.

And also you have to first learn about the ***access modifiers*** . The simple rule for accessing a member of another class is that, if that Class is visible and if its members doesn't have restrictive access then you can access them.

Comment: Do you usually access members of another class by using dot notation?

Comment: If they are not `static` then we have to access them via the dot notation. Here you might have to ask what is the reason for using `static` members? So, suppose you have one utility class with a method that always return say, a random number then you have to make that method static because it would always behave the same way regardless of which instance of the class performed the method.

Answer (score 0):

Using static you can archive that:

```
public class class1
{
public static string myname = "light";


}

public class2 {

public static void displayMyname()
{
    System.out.println(class1.myname);
}

    }
```

Notic that the method that display the values must be static as well.

Comment: I saw same thing. I think stackoverflow just glitched lolz. Thanks for the answer!!!